# Can I purchase a gift certificate online for steam that is NOT associated with a specific game?

Tags: steam

Sorry if this is a repeat question - I didn't see it on the steam FAQ or other questions on here.

I'd like to purchase a gift certificate for someone on steam and let them choose which game they want.  Is this possible?  Or can I only purchase/gift specific game titles?

Comment: I think it depends on which country you live in. In certain countries they sell cards(on GameStop and such) that is pre-filled with money. So they activate it on Steam and then the person can buy whatever they want for that amount.

Comment: @Redhawk Thanks.  I was hoping to find something online.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no online gift certificate or something similar. The closest thing i can think of is a pre-paid Visa. But that feels very unpersonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is such a thing as a [Steam Wallet Code](https://store.steampowered.com/account/redeemwalletcode), which will allow you to purchase a card and then have somebody redeem the value of that card against their Steam wallet online. However, these only appear to be available from select stores, and not available for purchase online.

In the UK this is pretty much limited to GAME, however you can find a full list of stores you can purchase Steam Wallet codes from in your country on the [Steam website](http://www.steampowered.com/wallet).

Your other options are transferring the money to them some other method (Paypal or similar) and your friend loading it onto their account themselves, or you purchasing the title that your friend is after and gifting it to their account.